# Platform Migration: Error when compiling project

Tags: macos, firebase, flutter, dart

A few weeks ago I started a Firebase course with flutter, and I was programming on a Windows computer, and now I've been using a Mac for a few days, to learn how to make firebase with iOS too. However, I have received these errors, and I do not know if I am missing a file, lines of code or if I have obsolete code. I tried some solutions I found on the internet, like deleting the files pubspec.lock, podfile, podfile.lock, reinstalling using pod init and pod install, but none of these solutions managed to solve the problem. I know very little about Swift / Objective-C, and this project is connected (android) on firebase.

```
/Users/mobileteam/Desktop/pasta_mary/aikoBot/aiko_bot/ios/Pods/FirebaseCrashlytics/Crashlytics/Shared/FIRCLSFABHost.m100:11: warning: 'UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 13.0 - Use -[UIDevice userInterfaceIdiom] directly. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]

  switch (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM()) {

          ^
In module 'UIKit' imported from /Users/mobileteam/Desktop/pasta_mary/aikoBot/aiko_bot/ios/Pods/FirebaseCrashlytics/Crashlytics/Shared/FIRCLSFABHost.m:20:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/Headers/UIDevice.h:97:36: note: 'UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM' has been explicitly marked deprecated here

static inline UIUserInterfaceIdiom UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() API_DEPRECATED("Use -[UIDevice userInterfaceIdiom] directly.", ios(2.0, 13.0), tvos(9.0, 11.0)) {    
                                   ^
1 warning generated.

/Users/mobileteam/Desktop/pasta_mary/aikoBot/aiko_bot/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift:14:18: error: cannot override with a stored property 'window'

    override var window: UIWindow?

                 ^

Flutter.FlutterAppDelegate:2:14: note: attempt to override property here

    open var window: UIWindow! { get set }

             ^

note: Using new build system

note: Building targets in parallel

note: Planning build

note: Constructing build description
```

Comment: try to follow this steps https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/installation/ios and make sure firebase is also register for IOS in ur firebase console

Comment: I already tried this one, it didn't work.